# Show 2 Array in 2 Textview on Listview

Tags: java, android

I have 2 `String array` .

array 1 and array 2 .
I want to show this 2 array in `listview` with search `filter`.

Can anyone suggest me any reference? I want to make it in one activity.  Like don't create another class for adapter.

Comment: just implement `ArrayAdapter` and pass your data into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this :

```
activity_list_view.xml
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewExample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

> This method use SimpleAdapter to show data in ListView.

```
private void simpleAdapterListView()
{


    String[] titleArr = { "1", "2", "3", "4","5"};
    String[] descArr = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };

    ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> itemDataList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();;

    int titleLen = titleArr.length;
    for(int i =0; i < titleLen; i++) {
        Map<String,Object> listItemMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        listItemMap.put("title", titleArr[i]);
        listItemMap.put("description", descArr[i]);
        itemDataList.add(listItemMap);
    }

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,itemDataList,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            new String[]{"title","description"},new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2});

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewExample);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int index, long l) {
            Object clickItemObj = adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(index);
            Toast.makeText(ListViewActivity.this, "You clicked " + clickItemObj.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

In the end just declare `this.simpleAdapterListView();` inside `onCreate();` .

Answer (score 0):

pass two arrays to list adapter and get data from arrays and set to text view.
[tutorial for listview](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can create inner class extending BaseAdapter in your activity class. No need to create separate class file.

Try following for using two textviews.

You need to create your_layout_containing_textViews.xml in layout folder and that should contain two text views.

```
pubic class MyActivity extends Activity {
 ....
....
....

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
// edits based on comments by the question author -- for two text views
        String[] str1 = new String[]{...};
        String[] str2 = new String[]{...};

        int getCount(){
            return str1.length > str2.length?str1.length : str2.length;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_layout_containing_textViews, null);
            TextView txt1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            TextView txt2 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
            txt1.setText(position<str1.length?str1[position]:"");
            txt2.setText(position<str2.length?str2[position]:""); 
            return convertView;
        }
 ...
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Can you please give a full reference?

Comment: Sure. But first please clarify your question. What type of arrays you have? Strings? How do you want to search??? Is data in these two arrays related in anyway?

Comment: Both are string.

Comment: Why don't you consider creating an ArrayList and adding both the strings to arraylist and use array adapter

Comment: I want to make it in custom adapter.  I have Implement 1 array successfully  but i want help with 2 array on 2 separate Textview.

Comment: Sorry to say i can't accept your answer.  Useless answer.